# How to count each letters from a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a cord.txt file as shown below,

```
188H,190D,245H
187D,481E,482T
187H,194E,196D
386D,388E,389N,579H
44E,60D
```

I need to count each letters and have to make a summary as shown below (expected output),

```
H,4
D,5
E,4
T,1
```

I know how to count each letters by using `grep "<letter>" cord.txt | wc`. But I have a huge file which contains more number of letters, therefore please help me to do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly:

```
tr '[0-9],' \\n <input | sort | uniq -c
     43 
      5 D
      4 E
      4 H
      1 N
      1 T
```

Ok, there are 43 other characters... You could drop and match your request by adding `sed`:

```
tr '[0-9],' \\n </tmp/so/input | sort | uniq -c |
     sed -ne 's/^ *\([0-9]\+\) \(.\)/\2,\1/p'
D,5
E,4
H,4
N,1
T,1
```

Answer (score 6):

You're missing the `N` :-)

```
grep -o '[[:alpha:]]' cord.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

- `grep -o` only outputs the matching part. With the POSIX class `[[:alpha:]]`, it outputs all the letters contained in the input.
- `sort` groups the same letters together
- `uniq -c` reports unique lines with their counts. It needs sorted input, as it only compares the current line to the previous one.

Answer (score 4):

The following command

1. Removes any character that is not an ASCII letter;
2. Places every character on its own line;
3. Sorts the characters;
4. Counts the number of same consecutive lines.

```sh
sed 's/[^a-zA-Z]//g' < input.txt | fold -w 1 -s | sort | uniq -c > output.txt
# ^                                ^              ^      ^
# 1.                               2.             3.     4.
```

Input:

```
188H,190D,245H
187D,481E,482T
187H,194E,196D
386D,388E,389N,579H
44E,60D
```

output:

```
 5 D
 4 E
 4 H
 1 N
 1 T
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use python's [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) as follows, let `cord.txt` content be

```
188H,190D,245H
187D,481E,482T
187H,194E,196D
386D,388E,389N,579H
44E,60D
```

and `counting.py` be

```
import collections
counter = collections.Counter()
with open("cord.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        counter.update(i for i in line if i.isalpha())
for char, cnt in counter.items():
    print("{},{}".format(char,cnt))
```

then `python counting.py` output

```
H,4
D,5
E,4
T,1
N,1
```

Note that I used `for line in f` where `f` is file-handle to avoid loading whole file into memory. Disclaimer: I used python version `3.7`, older should work but might give other order in output, as `collections.Counter` is subclass of `dict` and these do not keep order in older python versions.